# xampp cargó una vez no cargó mas phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

Mira desde ese día que lo ocupe no me quizo cargar el mysql y estoy desinstalando e instalándolo una y otra ves el xampp pero el problema sigue e intentando modificando los puertos desde 3306, 3307 y 3308 y no quiere abrirme el phpmyadmin quisiera saber si tu me prodrias ayudar con esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

No lo especificas pero si tienes otra aplicación para las bases de datos (*wamp, workbench, etc*) esto hace que no lo puedas utilizar si es que alguna de esas aplicaciones tiene el **puerto** de **sql** de xammp.

Lo que a mi me funcionó fue abrir en la ventana de **xammp/MySQL/Config/my.ini** y pulsa **ctrl+B** y del puerto que tenga cámbialos todos por otro puerto, por ejemplo, ve buscando cada *3306* y cámbialo por *3308*.

Edición:
Entra a configuración de **PHP/php.ini** y también busca los puertos *3306* y sustitúyelos por el puerto que pusiste en **My.ini**